# Combine google place and another json data

Tags: javascript, google-places-autocomplete

I'm trying to do a search box like Trivago, Tripadvisor, etc,. with google place geocomplete and another json with my places.

So, I need to combine  google place (for examle: https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/) 
and my json:

```
[
  {
    "link" : "http://es.mysite.local/restaurant/abluo-quidem-ut",
    "value" : "Abluo Quidem Ut",
    "fields" : {
      "title" : "Abluo Quidem Ut",
      "name" : "author: Anonymous",
      "comment_count" : "0 comment(s)"
    },
    "group" : {
      "group_id" : "restaurant",
      "group_name" : "Restaurant"
    }
  }, 
  {...}
]
```

I don`t know if the best way to do that :S

Any suggestion? just at least to know how analyze my problem. I'm totally lost.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you'll need to call some pretty run-of-the-mill functions on your array of results, probably `map` will be your best friend!

Comment: hi @JPSilvashy, thanks, but what do you mean about "map"? thank you a lot :)

Comment: Map is a function: https://codeburst.io/learn-understand-javascripts-map-function-ffc059264783 <= read this, and you should be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer (for me).
I did it with jQuery UI autocomplete and gecomplete google place in the same input.

With UI, I Load a Json with my places, products, etc... and with geocomplete get the data and then I generate a url to my destinations landings

If anyone have a better solution, are welcome! thanks all :)